# Pandas mishandling apostrophe when exporting to csv file

Tags: python, pandas

Pandas is mishandling apostrophes when exporting them to a csv file.  It is changing the apostrophe in "community’s" to "communityâ€™s".  The program first reads an Excel file into a dataframe, then merges that dataframe with another dataframe, and then exports the resulting dataframe to a csv file.  The apostrophe starts off looking like this in the input Excel file (' - a straight apostrophe), then looks like this after import (’ - a curly apostrophe), then looks like this after exporting to csv (â€™).  The numeric value I get when I use the Python ord() function on the curly apostrophe value in the dataframe "’" is 8217.

Here's some of the pertinent code.  Any thoughts on how to fix this?

```
xls_file = pd.ExcelFile(path + file)
df_cust_quests = xls_file.parse('CustQuests')

df_cust_combined = pd.merge(df_cust_clsend, df_cust_quests, on=['ServiceLine', 'QuestNum'], how='left')

df_cust_combined.to_csv('C:/Users/User/Desktop/Sample File.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: Try adding the `encoding='utf-8-sig'` option to `to_csv`.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution.  The Excel file I was importing contained curly apostrophes.  They looked straight because they were small, but when I looked at them closer I could see they were curly.  I changed them to straight apostrophes and that fixed the problem.